# How to access my 2nd internal harddrive?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have replaced Windows 7 with Ubuntu on my old PC. There is another internal hard drive in my old PC, that contains a lot of data.

I cannot access this hard drive, as it is not mounted.
This is how it looks.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   2.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-calculator/180
loop1    7:1    0  34.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/319
loop2    7:2    0    13M  1 loop /snap/gnome-characters/103
loop3    7:3    0  14.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-logs/37
loop4    7:4    0   3.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-system-monitor/51
loop5    7:5    0 140.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/70
loop6    7:6    0  86.9M  1 loop /snap/core/4917
loop7    7:7    0   4.9M  1 loop /snap/snapweb/319
loop8    7:8    0   3.3M  1 loop /snap/udisks2/100
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 232.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1   1.1G  0 rom
```

Needs help to mount this drive, without losing my existing data.
I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: First step is to look at the partition type, e.g. with `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` (as root) for textual output on the shell you can cut and paste when you edit the question. The `-l` (lower case ell) is important. Second step is to try to mount it, e.g. `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt` (as root) and see what happens, assuming you have a `/mnt` directory for mountpoints. Depending on how your system looks, `/media`, or a directory under one of these two will also work as a good mountpoint.

Comment: What is the output of "blkid" - that should show a list of block devices ?

Comment: sorry i do not understand the language " textural output" question". Is there any way that some one with a kind heart from a remote excess can help me with the the very basics of commands ?